# Weird Shiny polygons at mesh joining edge

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image: My Pictures are in reverse order This is what happened when I used a subdivide modifier Appears to have 2 sets of polys]I joined 2 meshes together, adding eye socket to the stalk for the eye on a crayfish. It almost looks like a ghost set of polys are making a translucent layer over the regular polys. The polys above the join edge are shinier and darker and I've tried to reset the material and that didn't help. I deleted a couple of rows of ploys and rebuilt it and the shiny just comes back. Ctrl L selects the whole model so the meshes are joined. The first picture is what happened when I tried adding a subdivision modifier. [image]
[image: t almost seems to glow like a prism effect.I]

Answer (score 0):

two things could have happened, when joining the meshes the normals were not correct, in edit mode, select the entire mesh and press shift+n to recalculate the normals.
If that doesn't work you may have duplicate faces, in edit mode again select the entire mesh and press the m key, in the dialog select "by distance" to join the overlapping duplicate faces.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you assistance. I'm honestly not 100% on how I finally fixed it, but It looks like the eye socket had Shade Smooth on separately from the body, but I also recalculated the normals, though I had to do it through the mesh drop down. When I tried ctrl N, Blender wanted to open a new file. I do appreciate you taking the time to help me out.

Comment: sorry, the shortcut to recalculate normals was "shift+n", my memory failed.